# How I can share resources between Xamarin.Android project and Xamarin.IOS project using portable class library

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, resources, portable-class-library, sharing

I created a new project contains a portable class library for Android and IOS, Then I created inside this solution two solutions for Android and the other one for IOS so I can share code between the two projects. I don't want to use Xamarin.Forms, I want to use Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.IOS.
My question is if I want to share resources like for example the strings.xml between Xamarin.Android project and Xamarin.IOS project, how I can do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you have two options. One is a Shared Project, the other is a Portable Class Library. Either way you would reference that project in your Android and your iOS project. Any resources or classes you have in the shared or portable project would then be usable by your application.

EDIT:

To provide something like different string translations as you support different Languages you would want to use a `.resx` (Resource File). You can do this from either Visual Studio or Xamarin Studio. With Visual Studio you can utilize the [Multilingual App Toolkit](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MultilingualAppToolkit.MultilingualAppToolkit-18308). While you do not want to use Xamarin Forms, I still believe this [tutorial for Xamarin Forms Localization](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/advanced/localization/) should at least help you understand their use more. Because you're not using native string localization, you may need to do a little more work in your Views to set the text values across the view.

Comment: Exactly, I have already PCL and I am looking for a way to share the multi languages support (file with strings for each language) to my Android and IOS project.

Comment: Thank you.
Is there anyway to share PNGs files from the PCL?

Comment: Resx files also support images. You can create a XAML extension similar to the one shown in the Localization tutorial to convert it to an ImageSource. If you need to support images for different Pixel densities like `@2x` or `@3x`, you will need to implement an interface to let you know which resource to grab since you're using shared images... That said you would be better off to follow the Localization example and keep the images in your platform specific project.

Comment: Will this work for raw assets (.ttf, .db3, etc.) in a [Standard Class Library](https://xamarinhelp.com/portable-class-library-pcl-vs-shared-projects/)? Thanks.

Comment: Yes .NET Standard libraries do support embedded resources